# Unable to get extras from an intent which is called using notification's pending intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

Below i am having code for two notifications and in intent i am passing extras with `key1` and `key2` but in `NotificationPillDescription.class` i am only able to get key1 using getExtras.

// Notification Code For First Notification

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Take your morning pill!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notifyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationPillDescription.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("Key1", String.valueOf(1));
    notifyIntent.putExtras(extras);

    contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notifyIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Take your Morning pill!", "My Drug", contentIntent);
                        notificationManager.notify(dataProvider.notificationId++, notification);
```

// Notification Code For Second Notification

```
notifyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationPillDescription.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("Key2", String.valueOf(2));
        notifyIntent.putExtras(extras);

        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notifyIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Take your Morning pill!", "My Drug", contentIntent);
                            notificationManager.notify(dataProvider.notificationId++, notification);
```

//Code for NotificationPillDescription.class

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras != null){
                if(extras.containsKey(String.valueOf(1)))
                {
                   Log.d("Pill Id0",extras.getString(String.valueOf(1)) );

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("Pill Id1",extras.getString(String.valueOf(2)) );
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

`extras.getString("Key1")` and  `extras.getString("Key2")`

instead of

`extras.getString(String.valueOf(1))` && `extras.getString(String.valueOf(2))`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here. It describes how to pass a bundle. I think your extras.getstring might not be enough. you might also not need to declare a bundle if you're using putextras.

Here:

[Passing a Bundle on startActivity()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity)

This might be helpful too:

[putExtras multiple putString not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241646/putextras-multiple-putstring-not-working)